# Подергивание при наведении на ссылку | html-css

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, header

В div'e есть список со ссылками. Когда наводишь курсор мыши на элемент списка, длина div'a увеличивается. Как это убрать?

```css
.header{
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.menu{
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 20px;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}

.menu li{
 margin: 1%;
 display: inline-block;
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
}
a:visited{ /*посещенная ссылка*/
 color: black;
}
a:hover{ /*при наведении курсора*/
 color: black;
 border-bottom: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>WebNote</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="">Login</a></li><li><a href="">Notes</a></li><li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит из-за добавления `border-bottom` при ховере. Можно добавить изначально его просто сделать невидимым `a {border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;}`

Comment: Спасибо, сработало.